# plt.plot scatter plot output issue

Tags: python

After running this block of code, I am getting 'Conversion Error' message:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.figure(figsize=(12.2, 4.5))
    plt.title('Buy and Sell Plot', fontsize = 18)
    plt.plot(df['Close'], label = 'Close Price', color = 'blue', 
     alpha = 0.35)
    plt.plot(ShortEMA, label = 'Short/Fast EMA', color = 'red', 
    alpha = 0.35)
    plt.plot(MiddleEMA, label = 'Middle/Medium EMA', color = 
    'orange', alpha = 0.35)
    plt.plot(LongEMA, label = 'Long/Slow EMA', color = 'green', 
    alpha = 0.35)
    plt.scatter(df.index, df['Buy'], color = 'green', 
    marker='^', alpha = 1)
    plt.scatter(df.index, df['Sell'], color = 'red', marker='v', 
    alpha = 1)
    plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize = 18)
    plt.ylabel('Close Price', fontsize = 18)
    plt.show()
```

**Any insight would be most appreciated**

Comment: ConversionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in convert_units(self, x)
   1574         except Exception as e:
   1575             raise munits.ConversionError('Failed to convert value(s) to axis '
-> 1576                                          f'units: {x!r}') from e
   1577         return ret
   1578 

ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: masked_array(data=[--, --, etc,etc.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the way you are calling the `scatter` function. I suspect the problem comes from the data in your dataframe. What exactly is inside `df.index`? Could you try commenting all lines except for `plt.scatter(df.index, df['Buy'], color = 'green', 
    marker='^', alpha = 1)` to help identify the problem?

Comment: Essentially, this is a moving average algorithm strategy meant to output 'buy' and 'sell' signals in the form of '^' and 'v (on the scatter plot containing three moving averages)'. I actually just reran the code block by inserting 'auc' in front of 'df.index.  Now, I can see a scatter plot instead of ConversionError masked_array(data=........ However, I can't seem to get those '^' and 'v' symbols to display in the scatter plot.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening due to the "`plt.scatter(df.index,`(...)" part. If you run `type(df.index)` you'll see it's a `pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex`, not an array.
Try running it with `np.asarray(auc_df.index)` instead, hope it'll fix the issue!

Comment: Actually, that feature gave me an output of a scatterplot containing three moving averages.  Unfortunately, the 'buy' and 'sell' signals (in the form of '^' and 'v') did not.

Comment: And thank you for taking time to aid a struggling novice with these coding dilemmas.